# Error while running ls command using tilde character in python script

Tags: python-2.7

When I use the tilde character in the subprocess call I'm getting an error. Otherwise the program runs fine.

**Program**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls","-lrth","~"])
```

**Error**

```
ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde (~) is the shell shortcut for the user home directory. If you want to list all the files/directories in the user home directory you can expand the path using 
**os.path.expanduser**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.call(["ls","-lrth",os.path.expanduser("~")])
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the below error:                           import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.
./lsCommand.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `["ls","-lrth",os.path.expanduser'
./lsCommand.py: line 4: `subprocess.call(["ls","-lrth",os.path.expanduser('~')])'

Comment: Updated the script with a shebang line (#!/usr/bin/env python). Can you try it ?